# Parse a text file: Efficiency and perfomance

Tags: java, parsing, etl

I'm in a small development project related to parsing text files (applying ETL approach). I have created a demo code that runs correctly in my local machine, but when I deploy it to the Apache Tomcat Container it generates a lot of errors related to memory overflow, type conversion, etc.

This is general fact:

This is the [file structure](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArfdLEVE609GdDVydTVSX0E4c29aejFaNE9PY0lDcXc&usp=sharing) (the notes specify the data type and other related info to each cell).

Note that **RegisterType1** repeats only once per customer, **RegisterType2** could repeats once or more times, **RegisterType3** and **RegisterType4** repeat once.

Also note that every register type varies in length, i.e.: RegisterType1 12 fields, RegisterType2 10 fields, and so on.

As I said previously, my current parser is so bad coded that it generates a lot of errors. [This is the actual code](http://pastebin.com/fzrktzqW) and [this one](http://pastebin.com/FH5J1MAM) (a class that creates db connections and execute queries).

This is an [example text file](http://pastebin.com/aH5ShwNJ) who requires to be parsed.

Current development environment
**Platform**: Java 6
**Container**: Tomcat 7
**VPS profile**: RAM 1.7GB, Storage: 20GB, Processor: (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650 @ 2.67GHz, 24 cores).

Actual issues:

- Poor perfomance
- Memory overflow
- Parsing errors: data type conversion, delimiters (semicolons) between fields (e.g.: ...Paris;Fran[semicolon here]ce;...)

I want to create an efficient, correct, and a high performance parser.

I need some suggestions to this topic. Which the best way to create a good parser?

Thanks in advance for you information.

Regards,

Comment: SO questions should be self-contained and understandable without going to external pages. This is because external pages may disappear, while SO question is supposed to stay valid indefinitely, for benefit of future visitors. If there is too much code to include in question, it is poor fit for SO.

Comment: Yeah - maybe you have some part in specific you know is holding it back?

Comment: Run on your local machine with the exact same input file as on the server and observe what happens.

Comment: @hyde I have a membership in Pastebin (so the service is also indefinitely).

But thanks for your suggestion (this is the last time I do that) ;).

Comment: @JohnOrtiz It's also general reluctance of many to click external links, as well as difficulty of drawing the line of what can be considered permanent external link (like, you could still delete those pastes...). But note that reference links are good and can help getting good answers, as long as it does not matter much if they break, and if knowledgeable person can answer the question without them.

Answer (score 1):

Post your relevant code here. OK, I will do some of this for you:

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    ArrayList< String> elements = new ArrayList< String>();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivoFuenteDatos));
        String text = null;

        // repeat until all lines is read
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        ...
        elements.add(...);
        ...
    } catch(...) ...

    saveOnDB(elements);
```

Don't ever read huge files like that. You have to hold all your data in memory at the same time if you do.

1. Try writing each entry directly to the database instead of copying to an array list first. This will hopefully fix the OOMs.
2. Profile your code. If it's fast enough, you are done.
3. If not fast enough, create an ArrayList. Give it an initial capacity `n`. Read no more than `n` items into that list before writing to the db.

EDIT:
If I haven't missed something important, you copied your own code 4 times. Please refactor prior to posting (too much code). For example the huge switch could be refactored to something like this:

```
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] campos = text.replaceAll(" +", " ").split(";");
            int n;
            switch (text.charAt(0)) {
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                    n = campos.length - 1;
                    break;
                case '4':
                    // what does this mean? It will always give 5!
                    // n = contarPuntoComas(text) == 6 ? 5 : 5;
                    n = 5;
                    break;
                default:
                    n= 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                 elements.add(campos[ i].trim());
            } // end for
        }
```

Comment: Hi @axel you give me a lot of ideas to attack the actual poor performance of the parser.

To split strings, would you recommend use RegEx?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend running a profiler first. But IMHO the problem is the ArrayList, since it has to be copied over and over again each time that the current capacity is insufficient. Plus you will get GC pauses because of that.

Comment: Another suggestion: How about replacing `campos = text.split(";");` and then calling `replaceAll` on each of the parts by instead doing something like `campos = text.replaceAll(" +", " ").split(";");` and removing the other calls to `replaceAll`? (But go for the ArrayList first!)

Comment: Do you know a way to create a parser who its source is a text file like the one above? Thanks in advance!